# Importing external functions and logic from another go file inside same directory

Tags: go, go-modules

I am new to golang and have been loving it so far. So far I've been writing all my applications logic inside the `main.go` and it is starting to get quite cumbersome with so much text on the screen. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import external functions that are located in another .go file. Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish

`main.go`

```
package main

func main() {
     SayHello() //THIS IS THE FUNCTION IMPORTED FROM hello.go
{
```

`hello.go`

```
package hello

import "fmt"

func SayHello() {
     fmt.Println("Hello!")
{
```

`project structure`

```
/
    -main.go
    -hello.go
```

I know this is a fairly simple question but everything I try will result in an error in my console. All I want in this example is to export the `SayHello` function from the hello.go file into the main.go file, and as far as I understand anything exported must start with a capital letter. The whole go.mod file and package declaration at the top if each file confuses me and I have not been able to figure this out for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a single package per directory. If you want the code in `hello.go` to live in a separate package, you need to move it into a subdirectory.

First, this assumes that you've initialized your project using `go mod init <something>`. For the purposes of this example, we'll start with:

```
go mod init example
```

This creates our `go.mod` file. Next, we set up the correct directory structure:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── hello
│   └── hello.go
└── main.go
```

`hello.go` is correct as written (well, once you fix the syntax errors in your posted code). We'll need to add an `import` to `main.go`:

```
package main

import "example/hello"

func main() {
    hello.SayHello() //THIS IS THE FUNCTION IMPORTED FROM hello.go
}
```

This will build an executable that produces the expected output:

```
$ go build
$ ./example
Hello!
```